# How to fetch row values from mysql database and fill into text boxes by clicking radio button without refreshing page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to fetch database values and fill into html text boxes by clicking radio button without refreshing page in php. How can I do this.

Example-

**database values-**

Emp_Id - 1

Name - Mike

Industry - IT

Country - UK

**HTML display is like this-**

```html
<input type='radio'> | 
1 |
Mike |
IT |
UK |
```

**Now if I click radio button then it must fill all text boxes in my html page
HTML Text boxes-**

```html
Employee ID : <input type='text' value='1'>

<br>
<br>

Name : <input type='text' value='Mike'>

<br>
<br>

Working Industry : <input type='text' value='IT'>

<br>
<br>

Country : <input type='text' value='UK'>
```

Hope you understand my requirements and help me at the earliest.

Comment: Take a look at AJAX, it should be perfect for this.

Comment: You need to use javascript and ajax do to this task. **Step 1:** store employee id for each radio button some where in your row using hidden field. **Step 2:** fetch it using javascript. **Step 3:** Send it via ajax. **Step 4:** fill the result in your textfields using javascript.

Comment: You bind an event on the radio button that makes an ajax call to your server-side that returns either ready html or values to be populated and after it's completed you switch the content. We can't really provide you code cause there is no way to know how you are connecting to your db, what server-side framework you are using etc etc.

Comment: You can use ajax for this

Comment: Can you please tell me rough code for the same. As I am new to Web Technology. I am using advance PHP, no framework. And database connectivity is something like $connect=('$localhost','$username','$password','$dbname');

Comment: There are many examples of how to do this if you look for it. StackOverflow isn't a platform where you can ask for code - we'll gladly help you troubleshooting once you've tried something, and reached an issue

Comment: @Qirel : I have done this thing by submit buttons, but the same strategy is not working for radio button. That is why I am asking for code.

Comment: "*Asking for code*", then you're in the wrong place. You are required to do research and attempt to solve it before asking a question. Many comments here mentions Ajax, I think that's a great approach - but you need to try it out on your own first, and come back if you get stuck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can send an AJAX request to the php script and make it either give back a json string containing the data that you then parse in JavaScript or just return the html structure you want to display.

jQuery has a very easy to use AJAX function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with help of "parseJSON" method of jQuery. all you need to do is create a Json string and keep it as radio buttons value.

```
$json = json_encode(array("id" => "1", "name" => "Mike", "dept" => "IT", 
"country" => "UK"));
echo '<input type="radio" name="employee" value="' . $json . '">";
```

And then you can get this value in jQuery. Like this:

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='employee']:checked").val();
```

And then parse the json data, like this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( radioValue );
```

And assign the values to the text boxes like:

```
//HTML
Employee ID : <input type='text' id='id' value=''>
Name : <input type='text' id='name' value=''>

// jQuery
$('#id').val(obj.id);
$('#name').val(obj.name);
```

This way you can get your desired result.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `$.parseJSON` is deprecated as of jQuery 3, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/